# Total derivative of a scalar field

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-forms

I am rereading Spivak's calculus on manifold and on page 89 I notice that he says if $f\colon \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, then $Df(p)\in \Lambda^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$. But it became not obvious to me why this is true, if we think $Df(p)$ as a linear transformation from $T_p\mathbb{R}^n$ to $T_p\mathbb{R}$.   But the first exterior power of $\mathbb{R}$ is just(naturally isomorphic to) $\mathbb{R}^n$, right? Can anyone helps to clarify what he meant there? Thanks!

Comment: Well, $Df(p) :\Bbb{R}^n \to \Bbb{R}$ is linear, so $Df(p) \in (\Bbb{R}^n)^*$. Spivak's notation with $\Lambda$ is if I recall correctly, slightly non-standard (see the last few pages of the book with the addendum, he has a few remarks on notation). At this stage, he has no inner product in mind.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thanks, I will check out the addendum!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume $D$ denotes the differential on functions. On $\mathbb{R}^n$ you have an inner product $g$, which gives a canonical isomorphism between $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $(\mathbb{R}^n)^*$ (a vector $v$ is mapped to $v^{\flat} \in (\mathbb{R}^n)^*$ such that $v^{\flat}(u) = g(v,u)$). You know that the differential $Df$ at each point is a linear map from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$, so $Df(p) \in (\mathbb{R}^n)^*$ for every $p \in \mathbb{R}^n$. But then
$$Df(p) \in (\mathbb{R}^n)^* \cong \mathbb{R}^n = \Lambda^1\mathbb{R}^n.$$

Comment: Thanks, I think you are right, the author indeed wants to use the inner product.

Comment: This is common practice in Riemannian geometry, it is good to keep in mind.

Comment: No, Spivak is abusing notation, and he says so in his Addendum. He is writing $\Lambda^k V$ for $\Lambda^k(V^*)$.

Comment: That does not make my answer wrong. That abuse of notation makes sense in certain circumstances, otherwise is just misleading.

Comment: My point is that, your principles notwithstanding, Spivak does not intend any isomorphism using inner products.

Comment: I am not sure why Spivak uses this convention (may be because there is no danger of confusion in all contexts he considers?). Perhaps you can add an answer with more details, I guess that would be helpful for the OP. I find rather misleading to identify $k$-vectors and $k$-forms in a general context.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you...I will go to check the addendum. It seems that identifying vector and cotangent vector via inner product is not a good practice, because it may not work in a more general setting? I haven’t learned differential topology/geometry yet but my professor seemed to have made that remark in class before.